# How dbms like Oracle, MySql and Sql Server manage "free space"?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

thish is a general question about the "big" database player. 
I want to know how these DBMS manage deleted record. In particular: does they free space and re-utilize that free space ?
Hope not to be off topic.
Thank you!

Comment: Too broad a question. Bing "internal fragmentation".

Comment: A general answer to general question: each one does it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, they mark a deleted record as deleted, and they keep track of how much free space is available (and where), and will reuse the storage eventually (for new or updated records), but not necessarily in a timely manner.